# What is the best way to expand DOM objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Sometimes you need to expand standard DOM nodes by JavaScript to save some custom info (e.g. state). I see two methods:

1. Use `data-*` attributes: `node.setAttribute('data-custom', value)`
2. Just put your data directly into the node object: `node.__customField = value`

Second method as I see is used on the **Google search page**. They put field "__jsaction" into button DOM object. **jQuery** uses some variation of this approach for its `.data()` method (it puts into node the field named like `jQuery2030201338223880156870.7588401902467012` which as I see stores an index of data chunk in their storage).

Disadvantage of both techniques is possibility of collisions (however jQuery solutions looks not so bad). But ... is their any other more reliable methods?